# Some profile pictures in my SP List have a egg shape

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have JSON code to format my SharePoint list. It contains profile pictures. And when I put the size "S" i get all round profile pictures, the same for size "M". But if i make it to "L". Not all the profile pictures are rounded anymore !!! Some got an egg shape. How can i solve this:
B.t.w: I posted an example. Is that example viewable? Because i can not see my own pictures i post.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideListHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "float": "left",
      "display": "flex",
      "flex-wrap": "wrap",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "align-items": "center",
      "justify-content": "space-around",
      "min-width": "300px",
      "min-height": "286px",
      "border-radius": "8px",
      "margin-right": "10px",
      "margin-bottom": "10px",
      "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighterAlt ms-bgColor-neutralLight--hover ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
              "display": "block",
              "height": "auto",
              "max-height": "96px",
              "max-width": "96px",
              "border-radius": "50%"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "src": "=getUserImage([$FotoE.email], 'l')"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

gr. P

Comment: Are you using gallery view as default view? If not, is there any particular reason of not using gallery/tile view?

Comment: I just tried using the JSON you provided and it is working fine for me - showing perfect round profile pictures. In your case all users have the profile pictures or not? Maybe they have added small size image as profile picture?

Comment: I use the default view. And the stranges thing is the proflle picture with size S and M aree ok, but not with L !!! Gr. P

Comment: I think you are using "List" view and not "Gallery" view, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think i also need an itteration through the listitems because not cards of listimes are shown.

Comment: I use the List view and not the Gallery view

Comment: It's so wired, I check the size of the picture is 96×72 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so wired, I check the size of the picture is 96×72 px.

[image]

These are the sizes corresponding to size, and since both m and s are less than or equal to 72 px, they can display square circles.

- Size=S | 48×48 px
- Size=M | 72×72 px
- Size=L | 300×300 px

I'm guessing this is due to the proportional scaling of the image, when the image is 96px wide, the height is automatically set to 72px.

I'm sorry, but I haven't found a better solution for now. Maybe you can change max-width and max-height to width and height. this will solve the problem of image scaling, but at the same time the image will be distorted.